# Assigning a command output to ARG variable in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, devops

I want to be able to assign an command's output to an ARG variable while inside a Dockerfile. For example:

```
ARG myvar=$(echo 'hello')
```

However, this gives me syntax error

```
ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 68: ARG requires exactly one argument
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You can't do that. The `$(...)` is a shell expression and isn't valid inside your Dockerfile (except in the context of `RUN` commands...which are executed in a shell).

Comment: Thanks. Whatever I was trying to do with this, I’ll accomplish instead with a RUN command.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct answer to the question, the way I solved this problem was by creating a bash script that is responsible for starting the Dockerfile build. The script runs the command I need and then passes it as an argument to the Dockerfile. Example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MY_VAR=$(echo 'hello')
docker build --build-arg MY_VAR=${MY_VAR} -t myapp .
```

And then the Dockerfile gets it:

```
ARG MY_VAR
# MY_VAR now equals 'hello'
```